# Remove all CSS and JS in magento

Tags: javascript, css, magento

I want remove all default magento JS and CSS by page.xml. I have tried to remove by using "removeItem" method, but it takes more effort (nearly 15 to 20 file).

Is there are any way to remove **only default magento's** JS and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Okay.

If I understand your problem correctly you want to change a parent rather than multiple child files.

Local.xml, that's your key to success. Rather than changing code in the individual files, you're changing a file that tells all the other files to change. Any layout handle can be targeted by any Magento layout file.

Check out your `<default>` handle, changing the includes would go something like this:

```
<default>
<reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <name>js/my_javascript.js</name>
        <params/>
    </action>
    <action method="removeItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/my_stylesheet.css</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

So rather than going into each child file and changing the includes you can simply change the parent file to be a recursive change across the site. This also works in reverse for adding includes by changing `removeItem` to `addItem`.

I hope this helps!

Cheers

Comment: Arthorax, Thanks for your valuable answer.I've already tried to remove css and JS using "removeItem" method and it works perfectly, but we need to write more than 50 lines to remove 15 to 20 files. I hope you understand what am trying to say ;)